# Representing a tree in R

Tags: r

Representing a tree in R from scratch has proven difficult conceptually for me.

I would like to represent a tree using a list. Node representation, seems easy enough, but the branches of the tree in my example are just as important at the main tree.

```
tree<-list()
tree[["node1"]]<-"hello"
tree[["node2"]]<-"world"
tree[["node3"]]<-tree
```

Above is my general attempt a a sort of tree with 2 levels. I would like my list to be of a format which i can use with the data.tree package.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use the ````data.tree```` package, why can't you use the package's own *data.tree* class to represent your trees?

Comment: The problem is that this is a very inefficient way to store and use these trees.  Attempting to implement Random Forest, or any bagging method using this tree structure represents how impossible these are to work with.